# With SignalR, is it possible to send only one person or group message?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, signalr, chat, message

Many sites, including MSDN, have exemplified sending messages to all clients.

For example; With Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage (), the message goes to all users.

What should be done if I just want to send a **message to a group of people** who are chatting?

**Or to send a message to a single contact ...**

***Thank you...***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can send to group of people by joining group like this

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }

    public Task LeaveRoom(string roomName)
    {
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, roomName);
    }
}
```

and send message to this group by

```
Clients.Group(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

you can check this link for more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups

Comment: you can send to single person by his connection id or by his username if you are using authentication like asp identity 
please up-vote the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no experience with SignalR. How do I use SessionID to send to a single contact? Or does SignalR offer a specific ContactID for this? Thank you very much.

Comment: you need to learn more about signalr Each Member connects to a hub get a unique connection id

Comment: I do not use Asp.NET Membership. Instead, I have my own membership system. I keep my own user information in the database.

For example,

James Bond, UserID {AF433-DA322 ......-.........} Uniqueidentifier

I am creating a connectionID for SignalR or I want to define a member. How do I relate to user information in my own database?

The purpose is to send a message to the member in the database.

For example;

GUID userID = {AF433-DA322 .......-..........} [James Bond :)]

Clients.User(userID).send(message);

Comment: Anyhow, how do you establish a relationship between the user and the database? How can I promote it?

Comment: you can use a dictionary to store your custom connection id with your database userid and get connection id by your user id then send message by it